# Android emulate/send ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent

Tags: android, android-intent, media, send, broadcast

I am trying to control universal music playback (play/pause, skip etc.) by emulating headset music controls. Is there a way to broadcast the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent? I tried the regular way with sendBroadcast() but it didn't work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
  long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 

  Intent downIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null); 
  KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, 
KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0); 
  downIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, downEvent); 
  sendOrderedBroadcast(downIntent, null); 

  Intent upIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null); 
  KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, 
KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0); 
  upIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, upEvent); 
  sendOrderedBroadcast(upIntent, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't seem to be working. I tried it using play music and doubletwist with&without headphones, but it didn't do anything. Are there any special permissions needed or any Android version limitations? I am using 4.1

Answer (score 2):

You can dispatch different KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_* to AudioManager

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE));
audio.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, 
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE));
```

This will only work for apps that listen to these media events by calling

```
AudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver or MediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver
```