# how to make custom incoming call screen in Android in android kitkat

Tags: android

I tried many ways , but didn't work on kitkat or lollipop

I need broadcast receiver with code that can answer the call by a button , please

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't answer the call. This is a system permission that you can't acquire.

Comment: I want to make small launcher , there is some launchers can do it

Comment: @AnirudhSharma That is the answer with no critique at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is system permission and you shouldn't do it, but I found nice solution to this. You can use `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` and send it once to answer a call and send it twice to reject it.

[Android emulate/send ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925896/android-emulate-send-action-media-button-intent)